# Azure shared cache

Tags: azure, caching

We have a website currently running on the on premises servers, and the website do use in memory caching.

We are planning to move the website on Azure platform.

There is a need to clear all the cache from the website which we do using a page www.mydomain.com/clearcache.aspx

Now on Azue, this request will go to a particular instance and will clear the cache from that instance, but the other instances will still have the cache and requests going to that instance will read from cache.

We want to clear the cache from all the instances of the web app. can you please advise on this.

Regards

Umesh Deshmukh

Comment: This doc on caching patterns is quite good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching. Also, welcome to the world of distributed caching :D

Comment: Please note that we are using PASS model to deploy the website on Azure

Comment: You mean PaaS? The same caching patterns still apply.

Comment: Hi @juunas . Yes I mean PaaS. How can i forcefully clear the cache from all the instances programmatically. Can you please also advice how I can verify this. If i have 2 instances running, How can i confirm that my request to a page will always go to a specific instance.  Thanks Umesh